# can i use any humbucker pick up (in my cas DiMarzio D Activator) on semi hollow body or hollow body guitars

Tags: electric-guitar

can i use any humbucker pick up (in my cas DiMarzio D Activator) on semi hollow body or hollow body guitars ? in other word, are humbucker pick ups in hollowbody guitars adjust specifically for them or they are as same as solid body guitars?

Comment: They are the same but they are usually PAF pickups. Putting high output ones will give more feedback. Why you want to do this? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0IdMdBhZ2Y0

Comment: "PAF pickups" is too vague. Do you mean the original Patent Applied For pickups Gibson used, or just a generic lower output humbucker? Either way a high output guitar pickup doesn't necessarily result in feedback. We don't know OP's signal chain, so it is hard to second-guess what might happen.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Absolutely! Gibson used the same humbuckers in Les Paul and ES-355s back in the day (in some instances they used a tighter pole-spacing on semi-hollows). Basically a builder would be grabbing a pickup from a parts bin or similar, and either installing it on a solid or semi-hollow body.

DiMarzio D Activator pickups will fit in any number of hollow-body guitars. Whether they are the best pickup for such an instrument is entirely up to personal tastes. Some jazz guitarists have used Dimarzio Super Distortion pickups; just because they are a high output pickup doesn't mean you will get feedback, as we don't know your preferred gain settings and amplifier choice.

Comment: They still do. Gibson uses Burstbuckers in some of the current ES-335 and Les Paul models (as well as other guitars).